# How to show html of link_to helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my link_to helper:

```
<%= link_to pdf.title, pdf.file.url(:original, false), target: :_blank  %>
```

This produces the following html:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/system/pdfs/files/000/000/005/original/cv.pdf">my pdf file!</a>
```

How can I print the same html in view?

**What I tried:**

1. Method

   `<%= debug (link_to pdf.title, pdf.file.url(:original, false), target: :_blank)  %>`

This produces the correct html. However, the html is displayed within a grey box.
[image]

I just need the string. I don't want the grey box, the dots or the hyphens. Further, someone noted that `debug` might not work in production.

2. Method

   ```
      <%= (link_to pdf.title, pdf.file.url(:original, false), target:
     :_blank).inspect  %>
   ```

This produces faulty html. As you can see, characters are escaped:

```
"<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/system/pdfs/files/000/000/005/original/cv.pdf\">CV</a>"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to escape the html if you want it to be displayed in the browser as raw text. `<%= html_escape(link_to(pdf.title, pdf.file.url(:original, false), target: :_blank)) %>`

Comment: @max If I do this, not the html is displayed, the link is displayed. I want the html to be displayed.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I need the produced html to be displayed, so it can be copied into a html-editor.

Comment: Ah you're right. Its because its an link_to returns an `ActiveSupport::Safebuffer` and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `debug`, you can just convert it into a string. For example:

```
<%= "#{link_to 'Google', 'https://google.com', target: '_blank'}" %>
```

This will output the following to the page:

```
&lt;a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;https://google.com&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: Thank you. From where did you get this information?

Comment: Clever. Rails has a pretty strong built in XSS protection which can be pretty frustrating and quirky at times. So when you call `h link_to("Nowhere", '#"')` Rails tries to be helpful by not (double) escaping the "string" since it is a "trusted" ActiveSupport::Safebuffer. This "hack" coeces the value into an untrusted string which is automatically escaped.

Comment: Another way to do this is just `link_to('Google', 'https://google.com', target: '_blank').chomp`

Comment: @Metaphysiker I just thought of it while reading your question. I've been living inside Rails for a while now.